# How to correctly fix an error while initializing Interstitial ads?

Tags: android, kotlin, ads, google-ads-api, interstitial

I have a singleton class for loading and displaying ads

```
object AdmobProvider {
    var countLoadAds = 0

    lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd
    private val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()

    fun init(activity: Activity) {
        MobileAds.initialize(activity)
        initInterstitial(activity)
    }

    private fun initInterstitial(context: Activity) {
        mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(context)
        if (!SubscriptionProvider.hasSubscription()) {

            mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = context.getString(R.string.interstitial_video)
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest)

            mInterstitialAd.adListener = object : AdListener() {
                override fun onAdClosed() {
                    super.onAdClosed()
                    Log.i("AdmobProvider", "onAdClosed: ")
                }

                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(p0: Int) {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(p0)
                    countLoadAds++
                    Log.i("AdmobProvider", "onAdFailedToLoad: $countLoadAds")
                    if (countLoadAds <= 3) {
                        initInterstitial(context)
                    } else {
                        callback?.Failed(true)
                    }
                }

                override fun onAdOpened() {
                    super.onAdOpened()
                    Log.i("AdmobProvider", "onAdOpened: ")

                }

                override fun onAdLoaded() {
                    super.onAdLoaded()
                    Log.i("AdmobProvider", "onAdLoaded: ")
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
                        callback?.Success(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun showInterstitial() {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
            mInterstitialAd.show()
        }
    }

}
```

I load ads via

ActivityA in onCreate()

```
AdmobProvider.init(this)

override fun Success(state: Boolean) {
        Handler().postDelayed({
            val intent = Intent(this@ActivityA, ActivityB::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("ActivityB", 1)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }, 200)
    }
```

and show
in ActivityB in onCreate()

```
if (intent.getIntExtra("ActivityB", 0) == 1) {
    AdmobProvider.showInterstitial()
}
```

While I tested it on the phone and emulators everything was fine, but from users, a crash began to arrive in the ActivityB, mainly on Android 8+

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MainActivity}: d.m: lateinit property mInterstitialAd has not been initialized
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3455)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3598)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2164)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7582)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
Caused by: d.m: lateinit property mInterstitialAd has not been initialized
    at .b.i(Unknown Source)
    at .MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7822)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7811)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1328)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430)
```

I understand what the error is, but I can't figure out how to fix it correctly, because if I initialize an advertisement in the second activity, I will need to load it there, but it doesn't suit me. According to statistics, 88% of cases crash in background. Please tell me how to fix it correctly?

Comment: You can't create an InterstitialAd passing one activity and showing on another one. You should pass the Activity where it is going to be shown. Your current singleton approach is not a good idea. You should initialize the service once and preload any ad, then when thee time is appropriate, show it and load another one on background.

Comment: @m0skit0 okay, but I still don’t understand how to do it correctly, you can share a piece of code or a link to read about this, it’s very important for me that the ads is loaded exactly during the first activity and shown immediately as soon as the transition to the second activity occurs!?

Comment: No, the loading should be done *before* any activity is shown. Showing it is trivial once it is loaded already. Your solution is valid (although I don't like singletons) but separate the loading from the showing.

Comment: @m0skit0 It seems like this is how it works, I initialize and load the ads in ActivityA and show it in ActivityB, the only problem is that for some reason it is not always initialized, I tried to transfer the init from the activity to the application class, but there I cannot send the correct context of the activity

Comment: Still you cannot pass Activity A context to the ad and show it in Activity B, the context is not the same. Even if you solve the initialization problem it won't work. Post the code where you initialize and where you show it.

Comment: @m0skit0 I updated the question and noticed that in the statistics, most crashes in background

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @m0skit0 Updated the question

Comment: Sounds like showInterstitial() is called before init(). It could be that the app has been killed and when going back to the activity,  AdmobProvider is recreated as well from scratch, thus mInterstitialAd has not been initialized yet.

Comment: @m0skit0 I was thinking about this option that's why I added an intent check from the desired activity, if intent doesn't come right or doesn't come at all AdmobProvider.showInterstitial () should not be called. I updated the question

Comment: I already told you how to fix it correctly though: " You should pass the Activity where it is going to be shown. Your current singleton approach is not a good idea. You should initialize the service once and preload any ad, then when thee time is appropriate, show it and load another one on background". The intent fix is just a workaround hack instead of fixing the root issue: the singleton pattern. Do you use any kind of architecture? The activity should not even be responsible of loading the ads.

Comment: @m0skit0 There is no normal architecture, the code was inherited by me ((Do you propose to move the preloading of the ads to the service and enable it at the same time as the application, or I misunderstood?

Comment: When requesting to show an ad, make sure it is already loaded. You probably need it to be nullable, not lateinit. A better approach would be to have the ad loading on a separate ad repository that handles all this by itself when requested for an ad and injecting it into a view-model. I suggest you start separating concerns already for this feature, don't continue to do everything on the activity.

Comment: @m0skit0 Ok, thanks I will try to dig in this direction